# Preload an entire Bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Long time reader, first time poster.

I have recently started learning to use bootstrap.

I am stuck trying to get the a Bootstrap carousel to preload showing a spinning wheel (or similar effect).

I have pieced together the effect I'm going for, my first four images 'flick through' and the carrousel stops on my final image – but what I can't manage is to have the entire carousel content load behind a spinning wheel before the carousel starts.

This is my work in progress – http://maxsendak.com/test/pu_v2/max.html – so you can see, it is the whole header tag that needs to load with a 'load in progress' before it fires the carousel script and starts flicking through the slides.

```
<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-wrap="false">

<!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
<!-- START big image panel --><div class="item active">
<div id="top" class="header" style="background-image:url('http://www.maxsendak.com/test/pu_v2/img/people/max/1.jpg');">
<div class="text-vertical-center people_text_over_image">

</div>
</div>
</div><!-- END big image panel -->
<!-- START big image panel --><div class="item">
<div id="top" class="header" style="background-image:url('http://www.maxsendak.com/test/pu_v2/img/people/max/2.jpg');">

</div>
</div><!-- END big image panel -->
<!-- START big image panel --><div class="item">
<div id="top" class="header" style="background-image:url('http://www.maxsendak.com/test/pu_v2/img/people/max/4.jpg');">

</div>
</div><!-- END big image panel -->
<!-- START big image panel --><div class="item">
<div id="top" class="header" style="background-image:url('http://www.maxsendak.com/test/pu_v2/img/people/max/3.jpg');">

</div>
</div><!-- END big image panel -->
<!-- START big image panel --><div class="item">
<div id="top" class="header" style="background-image:url('http://www.maxsendak.com/test/pu_v2/img/people/max/5.jpg');">
<div class="text-vertical-center people_text_over_image">
<h1>Max Wilson</h1>
<h3>Creative</h3>
<br>
<a href="#about" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">See More</a>
</div>
</div>
</div><!-- END big image panel -->

</div>

</header>
```

Script to fire carousel needs to fire *after* everything is loaded.

```
<!-- Script to Activate the Carousel -->
<script>
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 500, //changes the speed
    pause: "none",
})
</script>
```

As is often the case when I'm learning my way around these things, I think it might be that I am missing something simple – is this the case?

Comment: It seems like you are using background images on your slides, do you? Maybe you should check the "Widgets/Javascript/Script" section of [aFarkas/lazysizes](https://afarkas.github.io/lazysizes/)

Comment: I did look as far as the "widgets..." section but nothing from there worked in the setup I have.

Comment: Check out [Owl Carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/lazyLoad.html)

Answer (score 3):

Remove the data-ride="carousel" - this is what triggers the carousel to start moving at page load. Instead you can start the carousel manually with javascript whenever you are ready with

```
$('.carousel').carousel()
```

Note - if you want to wait till your images have all loaded. You'd put this manual start in a window load like so

```
$(window).load(function() {
     // + any other carousel related stuff that has to wait for the images to complete loading
     $('.carousel').carousel()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery solution would be adding `d-block` to all `.carousel-item` elements, and placing this at the bottom, after `<body>` tag:

```
$(window).on("load",function() {
     $('.carousel-item').removeClass("d-block");
})
```